# DLL access application's data

Tags: c++, dll

I know similar questions have been asked before, but still things are not clear to me.

My application has a class, say `ClassAppGraph`, to represent some sort of graph. I need to write a DLL which parses an object of `ClassAppGraph` and do something.

How can my DLL access an object of `ClassAppGraph` from Application?

I know I can send a pointer to this object from application to the DLL, but then how does the DLL know what the class looks like, what are its data members and functions? Do I included a .h file in my DLL project which includes the declaration of the application class?

Is there any other design can I do for such a situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your application loads the DLL, they share the same memory space and your functions in the DLL can access any application process memory. Just make the instance globally accessible (e.g. global static variable). In the DLL source code, include the header file of `ClassAppGraph`, then you can use `ClassAppGraph *` directly in the DLL.

Comment: Note that there is no validation by the runtime environment that the class definition is the same on both sides.  This means that inconsistancies in class versions and many subtle things (such as default calling convention, field packing and other compiler flags) can cause interaction to corrupt the DLL's view of the exported object.

Comment: Looks like both the application and DLL are written by OP. I do not think version conflict will be problem because the application still links with the static lib.

Comment: @Cred King: Is making the instance globally accessible the only option to expose the object to DLL? Can't I pass a pointer to the object as a parameter to a function in the DLL?

Comment: Note: I would have tried out some of the things myself, but I need to write soon sort of a proposal to separate out a piece of application as DLL and develop it independently. Thanks for the answers. It will help me a lot.

Comment: Global variable is just an example. You can pass it as parameter to a function. To start with, just consider DLL code as a different class of your application. What can you do to a class instance? Later you will discover unique characteristics of DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the `ClassAppGraph` class and implementation in the DLL, and then in the application use the implementation from the DLL. Most likely I would actually make a `ClassBaseGraph` for the DLL, and if the application needs customization of the class it could inherit it.

Comment: I need to keep the DLL minimalistic and hence bringing class `ClassAppGraph' and its implementation to DLL has to be the last option.